# Is it legal to allow some employees to work from home, and others not?

Tags: telecommute, legal, equality

Running on very little information here, but I have heard that it is illegal to offer remote opportunities to some employees and deny it to others.

I understand there are going to be some situations where this does not work.. IE desk work vs manufacturing.. and all sorts of other catches.. my question is for 2x people doing the same work. Can one be allowed and other denied, legally?

Can anyone provide any specific laws or cases that back this up?

Comment: It's illegal where, exactly? This sounds like a question for a local law expert.

Comment: Fairly certain a boss can set whatever rules he/she likes in a situation such as this.  Only real law, at least in the US, is they can't limit or force you to work from home for reasons listed in the EEO.  Basically they can't say "well you're a woman, you can't work from home".  At least from my understanding.

Comment: Hopefully there is nowhere on this wretched planet with such a ridiculous regulation.

Comment: There are a variety of reasons why a manager/company would disallow certain individuals from working remotely. Some people need supervision, others don't. Some projects require on-site contact, others don't. The list goes on.

Comment: The real question is did you specifically ask your manager why some folks are allowed and others not? I would imagine if you asked your boss he would give a very specific reason and based on that reason you should make a determination if it breaks your local laws.

Comment: While the core question is on-topic (any manager should know the answer to this), the last sentence makes this off-topic as you seem to be primarily after legal information rather than solving an actual problem you're facing. @JoeStrazzere's second comment is spot-on though.

Comment: If you specifically just want to know about legal aspects (sounds like it) then there is also http://law.stackexchange.com (e.g. for help finding specific laws and cases).

Comment: You didn't say in which country or state this question was for?

Answer (score 9):

You do not generally have to give benefits equally to all people.  The ability to work from home is a privilege not a right. It may be granted only to those who are high performers or senior or only to those with a personal situation requiring them to work from home such as a cancer patient with a compromised immune system. It may be by job category (it is hard for the receptionist to work from home!). New employees may not be allowed until it is certain their performance is up to snuff. It may only be granted to those people who do not live in the same place as the office. There may be limitations on your network as to how many remote workers it can handle.

If your coworkers are allowed to work from home and you are not and you are in the same job, then I would suggest that you look to your own performance.

Comment: In the US, "benefit" has a specific meaning and in many cases they are required to be the same for people in the same class.  Typically though they're talking about compensation such as a certain type of insurance, etc. Obviously, working remotely isn't a benefit in that context, but I'm just clarifying.

Comment: It could also be a matter of trust, i.e. you haven't been there long enough where your employer is confident that you're a good candidate for completely unsupervised work.

Answer (score 8):

> Can one be allowed and other denied, legally?

Yes.  In the jurisdiction where I live (USA) this is legal.

With that said, there **are** a number of laws in the USA that prevent discrimination.  For example, I cannot deny a worker the right to work remotely because of his or her: race, color, religion, class, gender, sexual orientation, age, disability, or citizenship status.

If you believe you are the victim of discrimination in the workplace you may have legal grounds for a lawsuit, and may want to contact an attorney.

Comment: And by the same token, a person could be granted permission to work remotely BECAUSE of a disability, such as an accommodation for that disability. As a result, others may not be offered that opportunity because of the lack disability (i.e. an accommodation is not needed)